# How to find the duplicate values for every row in a PySpark column?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a very large pyspark dataframe which contains a string column with values like: data = '1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,4,5,7'.

I want to create another column in the same dataframe called 'duplicates' which should find if there are any duplicates in the 'data' column. If duplicates are found then it should enter 'yes' otherwise 'no'. The duplicate elements can be duplicate of a single digit or multiple digits from the data column, in all cases even if a single digit is repeated then the duplicate column will have a 'yes' value.  How do I achieve this in PySpark? I am using spark 3.0.1

| data | duplicates |
| --- | --- |
| '1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,4,5,7' | yes |
| '1,2,3,4,5' | no |
| '1,2,3,4,6,7,7' | yes |
| '1' | no |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for existence of duplicates, by comparing the [`size`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.size.html?highlight=size#pyspark.sql.functions.size) of the array before and after applying [`array_distinct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_distinct.html).

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [('1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,4,5,7',),
 ('1,2,3,4,5',),
 ('1,2,3,4,6,7,7',),
 ('1',), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("data", ))

split_expr = F.split("data", ",")
distinct_element_expr = F.array_distinct(split_expr)

(df.withColumn("duplicates", F.when(F.size(split_expr) == F.size(distinct_element_expr), 
                                    F.lit("no"))
                              .otherwise(F.lit("yes")))
   .show(truncate=False))

"""
+---------------------+----------+
|data                 |duplicates|
+---------------------+----------+
|1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,4,5,7|yes       |
|1,2,3,4,5            |no        |
|1,2,3,4,6,7,7        |yes       |
|1                    |no        |
+---------------------+----------+
"""
```